# Save a (.txt) file to the Assets Folder in Android?

Tags: android, android-assets

How to write to .txt file in assets folder.

How to get path assets folder ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't. The assets folder is read-only at runtime.

Pick a different location to save your data, see [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for more information.

Comment: it is still the same ?? its gonna be 2017 soon  ?

Answer (score 15):

The path of assets folder is **file:///android_asset** But this is read-only.

The assets folder is like folders res, src, gen, etc. These are all useful to provide different files as input to build system to generate APK file for your app.

All these are read-only while your app is running. At run-time you can only write to SD card.

I hope you understand my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Not possible,

Better you choose internal storage to save your txt file. [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Hope this will help you to understand.

Comment: how to save users login and password in text file? 
in user.txt
login
password
login1
password1
login2
password2
....

Comment: why should you use txt file, better option write it on XML file. so that you make flexibility whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do this, because of if you read and write both at runtime then everything could be change and application will behave unexpected which could be harmful or may be crashed. i suggest you to use internal memory, sqlite and app SharedPreferences etc.