# Android copying xml file from assets to internal memory

Tags: android, xml

Hi i have an xml file that contains the data I'm going to use to populate my app. i need to be able to read/write this file which i believe is not possible as it becomes a static resource in the assets folder. Is there a way on launch to copy this file to a location where i can use it in this way? or what is the best way to read and write a xml from a local resource?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Yes you can not **write** file in the assets folder at run time. For info [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781809/save-a-txt-file-to-the-assets-folder-in-android), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760626/how-to-write-files-to-assets-folder-or-raw-folder-in-android)

You can use below code copy from assets to sdcard then you can write it.

```
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();           
    InputStream in = assetManager.open("yourxmlfile.xml");
    File SDCardRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Folder");   
    SDCardRoot.mkdirs(); 
    File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"hello.xml");
    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufferLength = 0;
    while((bufferLength = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
           fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    }
    fileOutput.close();
```

And also don't forget to add **read/write** permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```